# how to print the values of excel cell using openpyxl of multiple rows and multiple column?

Tags: python-2.7

```
from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook

s1="test2.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(s1)
index1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
rownum=3

for row_i in range(3,21):
    for col_i in range(3,21):
        no=(index1.cell(row=row_i,column=col_i))
        print no

wb.save(s1)
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there a problem with the code you posted? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: I need to print the values from of multiple columns and rows. The above code is printing value as "None"